# Stopping rotation within a specific amount of spins

Tags: torque, rotational-kinematics

I have a disc spinning with a known angular velocity $\omega_o$.

I have to make it stop in exactly $N$ spins using a torque ecuation that looks like this :
$$\tau(t) = -B·t$$

Which is the correct expression of B?
[image]

I have no clue.

I tried doing the following:
$$\tau(t) = -B·t = I·\alpha(t)$$
$$\alpha(t)=\frac{-B·t}{I}$$
Then integrate twice:
$$\theta(t)= \frac{-B·t^3}{6I}+\omega_ot = N2\pi$$
And then I get the following, which is probably wrong and makes no sense:
$$B=  \frac{-(N2\pi-\omega_ot)6I}{t^3}$$

Help anybody?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is when you equate $\theta(t)=2 N \pi$ Of course you don't have $\theta$ constant at any moment in time. What you have is that after some time $t_0$ the disk has turned $N2\pi$, i.e.
$$\theta(t_0) = N 2\pi = -\frac{Bt_0^3}{6I}+\omega_0 t_0$$

and after the same time the disk is said to have stopped:

$$\dot{\theta}(t_0) = 0 = -\frac{Bt_0^2}{2 I}+\omega_0$$

Solving for B, I get:

$$N3\pi/\omega_0 = t_0$$

$$B= \frac{2I\omega_0}{t_0^2} = \frac{2I\omega_0^3}{(3\pi N)^2}$$